# Deny access but allow robots i.e. Google to sitemap.xml

Tags: web-crawler

Is there a method where you can only allow robots such as Google, Yahoo, or other search engine robots to my sitemap which is located at http://www.mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml. Is this possible to not allow direct access by a user but only to robots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well basically no, but you could do something with the user-agent string and disallow access (assuming Apache)

```
<Location /sitemap.xml>
  SetEnvIf User-Agent GodBot GoAway=1
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Deny from env=!GoAway
</Location>
```

But as it says [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#env) (where I found the syntax)

> Warning:
>
> Access control by User-Agent is an
>   unreliable technique, since the
>   User-Agent header can be set to
>   anything at all, at the whim of the
>   end user.

Answer (score 2):

It is in Red in my source:

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"];
$host = gethostbyaddr($ip);

if(strpos($host, ".googlebot.com") !== false){
    readfile("sitemap.xml");
}else{
    header("Location: /");
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily help the OP, since he/she didn't indicate a specific language.

Answer (score 0):

**sitemap.php**

```
<?php

    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"];
    $host = gethostbyaddr($ip);

    if(strpos($host, ".googlebot.com") !== false){
        readfile("sitemap.xml");
    }else{
        header("Location: /");
    }
```